# How can I soften mastic gum so it is easier to chew?

Tags: greek-cuisine, plant-based

I want to use mastic gum as a chewing gum but it's a bit too hard and I find myself hurting my  mouth with it. What natural plant ingredient (not wax) can I add to it to soften it so that it works better?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add oil (such as olive oil or vegetable oil) which will soften the mastic. Heat the oil then mix with the mastic and cool. Here is a [recipe](https://masticlife.com/en-us/blogs/news/recipe-olive-oil-flavoured-with-chios-mastic-gum), for example.
2. If you decide not to add anything, you can also suck on it like candy, which will [soften](https://masticlife.com/pages/chew-raw-mastic#:%7E:text=Put%20a%20tear%20of%20mastic,you%20can%20then%20start%20chewing.) the mastic and make it easier to chew.